# Accessing Certificate and Key from AWS secrets manager to be used in Gunicorn configuration

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, gunicorn, fastapi

I have store a ssl cert file and key file in AWS secrets manager.
I need to use those files for running gunicorn in HTTPS mode using following commnand:

gunicorn --certfile=server.crt --keyfile=server.key test:app

How can I access this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is a certificate issued by AWS ACM, then you can't export the private key so you won't be able to use it like this. If this is a certificate issued by some other service that you have imported into AWS ACM, then you can get the key files with the `aws acm export-certificate` [AWS CLI command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/acm/export-certificate.html).

You would have to run the AWS CLI command to export the certificate, then run the `openssl` command also detailed in the documentation I linked to decrypt the private key, and save all that to the file system before running your `gunicorn` command.